# Problem adding records to a Firebase collection using Flask & Python

Tags: python, firebase, api, flask

I'm using the Firebase SDK with Flask to develop an API and I can retrieve records using GET but can't insert records using a PUT/POST into a Firebase collection. The strange thing is that I get no errors or exceptions when executing the code but no records are added to the collection. Here's the code snippet.

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db=firestore.client()
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/offers',methods = ['PUT'])
def put_offer():
    try:
        cc_code = db.collection('offers').add({'offer_email': 'foo@foo.com'})
        print( "cc code = ", cc_code )
        return( '200' )
    except Exception as e:
        return f"An Error Occured: {e}"

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a new python program and called

```
subprocess.run("python3 ./addoffer.py", shell=True )
```

this was not a fix but a workaround!